# How to get rid of NVIDIA Settings?

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, windows-11, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-settings

**tl;dr** *I have uninstalled NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070's driver from my laptop, but I cannot get rid of corresponding NVIDIA Settings program, because it does not appear anywhere within the system except for tray. Can someone help me and give me the magic recipe on removing it?*

---

My PC (Asus Vivobook 14X, if that matters) has two graphic cards. Embed AMD chipset one and much powerful NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070. For private reasons I decided to get rid of the second one's driver and fallback to using AMD chipset one.

However I have a huge troubles getting rid of NVIDIA Settings program and a corresponding nag screen that I see each time I restart my PC:

[image]

I cannot install NVIDIA Settings any method known to me, because it does not appear anywhere else except for the tray / notification area.

It does not appear among Settings' *Add or Remove Programs* section:

[image]

I cannot find it in Control Panel's *Add or Remove Programs* applet:

[image]

And when searching through Start Menu system finds only some old PC's driver setup program:

[image]

There's no sign of it around startup programs:

[image]

I have located the corresponding service, but I can only stop it and turn it into manual startup, but I can't uninstall it this way:

[image]

So, is there any way to permanently get rid of NVIDIA Settings or do I have to learn to live with it?

Comment: You uninstalled the driver.  If there is still an item starting up, I suggest trying to find it with Autoruns (Microsoft SysInternals).  You can delete Nvidia entries that show up in Autoruns.

Comment: try reinstalling GeForce Experience and then properly uninstalling it.

Comment: @Mokubai Nope, still nothing. My Windows 11 has nothing around "Geforce". BTW: There's a deleted (by the post author) answer below. I don't know why it was deleted as it turned out to be correct answer (uninstalling NVIDIA Geforce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU from Display Adapters did solve the problem). Since you're a moderator then a question to you, if this answer can be resurrected somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard driver package from Nvidia includes the control panel. See if you still have Nvidia drivers in Device Manager > Display Adapters. If so, remove & restart to see if that clears the popup.

Comment: Welcome to the society and thank you for the straight-to-the point answer. Yes, indeed removing the obsolete driver from _Device Manager_ did solve the entire problem.